# libformulaErrorValue error code 504

Tags: kettle

I'm building a formula using step where I want to secarch for a string within a char column
IF(FIND("PUC";UPPER([DSC_LONGDESC])>0);"PUC";"OTHERS")
but I'm getting this error when I run the tranformation
libformulaErrorValue error code 504 error message not found

any help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
IF(ISBLANK([DSC_LONGDESC]);"OTHER";
IF(ISERROR(FIND("PUC";UPPER([DSC_LONGDESC])));"OTHER";
IF(FIND("PUC";UPPER([DSC_LONGDESC])>0);"PUC";"OTHERS")))
```